# python dynamic logs directory logging.config

Tags: python, logging

I'm using `logging.config` for a script -

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('t_deploy.log', 'a')
```

In my `app.py` file I have a couple of variables being generated -

```
current_datetime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")
current_user = getpass.getuser()
```

How do I pass those variables to get the `t_deploy.log` file to generate in the folder I want.

ex.

```
"\\\blah\\location\\%s-$s" % (current_datetime, current_user)
```

Comment: logging.config.dictConfig() offers more flexibility in this area than the older logging.config.fileConfig() API, so I would recommend that you consider switching.